# How to limit nested multifield in AEM?

Tags: aem

I am using nested multifield for touch UI in AEM 6.1 and I have requirement to limit the multifield , I already saw acs common (maxItems--validation)but its not helping me .
Please provide your guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can achieve this.You can try the below steps:

1) Create the clientlib folder under your component with `categories (String[]) - cq.authoring.dialog`
2) In the js file write the below code:

```
(function($, $document) {
    "use strict";

    $document.on("dialog-ready", function() {
        var fieldErrorEl = $("<span class='coral-Form-fielderror coral-Icon coral-Icon--alert coral-Icon--sizeS' " +
            "data-init='quicktip' data-quicktip-type='error' />");
        var currentTimeMillis = new Date().getTime();
        var countValidatorId = "multifield-validator-" + parseInt(currentTimeMillis);

        var $countValidatorField = $("#" + countValidatorId),
            $multifield = $("div.coral-Multifield"),
            fieldLimit = 3,
            count = $multifield.find(".coral-Multifield-input").length;
        $.validator.register({
            selector: $countValidatorField,
            validate: validate,
            show: show,
            clear: clear
        });

        $multifield.on("click", ".js-coral-Multifield-add", function(e) {
            console.log("Add Called");
            ++count;
            adjustMultifieldUI();
        });

        $multifield.on("click", ".js-coral-Multifield-remove", function(e{
            --count;
            adjustMultifieldUI();
        });
        function adjustMultifieldUI() {
            $countValidatorField.checkValidity();
            $countValidatorField.updateErrorUI();
            var $addButton = $multifield.find(".js-coral-Multifield-add");
            if (count >= fieldLimit) {
                $addButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                var arrow = $multifield.closest("form").hasClass("coral-Form--vertical") ? "right" : "top";
                fieldErrorEl.clone()
                    .attr("data-quicktip-arrow", arrow)
                    .attr("data-quicktip-content", "Limit is 3")
                    .insertAfter($multifield);

            } else {
                $addButton.removeAttr('disabled');
                $multifield.nextAll(".coral-Form-fielderror").tooltip("hide").remove();
            }
        }
        function validate() {
            if (count <= fieldLimit) {
                return null;
            }
            return "Limit set to " + fieldLimit;
        }
        function show($el, message) {
            this.clear($countValidatorField);

            var arrow = $multifield.closest("form").hasClass("coral-Form--vertical") ? "right" : "top";

            fieldErrorEl.clone()
                .attr("data-quicktip-arrow", arrow)
                .attr("data-quicktip-content", message)
                .insertAfter($multifield);
        }
        function clear() {
            $multifield.nextAll(".coral-Form-fielderror").tooltip("hide").remove();
        }
    });
})($, $(document));
```

You have to do the refactoring of this code and removed some unused properties, but can give you start. Also make sure your js is getting call once you open the dialog. Happy Diwali Dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
        The solution works in AEM 6.3, the limit is configured in the dialog instead of hard coding it. This helps configure the value individually for each component.

            (function ($, $document) {
            "use strict";
            $(document).on('dialog-ready', function (e) {
            var multifieldLimit = $('.cq-Dialog').find('coral-multifield').find('section').attr("data-maxmultifieldlimit");
              if(multifieldLimit) {
                $('.cq-Dialog').find('coral-multifield').children('button').each(function(i) {
                   $(this).click(function(e){
                    var itemCount = 0;
                    $('.cq-Dialog').find('coral-multifield').children('coral-multifield-item').each(function(i) {
                      itemCount+=1;
                    });
                    if(itemCount==parseInt(multifieldLimit)){
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      alert('You have added maximum number of items in this multifield');
                    }
                   });
                });
              }
            });
            $document.on("click", ".cq-dialog-submit", function(e){
              var minMultifieldLimit = $('.cq-Dialog').find('coral-multifield').find('section').attr("data-minmultifieldlimit");
                if(minMultifieldLimit) {
                var itemCount = 0;
                $('.cq-Dialog').find('coral-multifield').children('coral-multifield-item').each(function(i) {
                  itemCount+=1;
                });
                if(itemCount<parseInt(minMultifieldLimit)){
                  alert('You have to at least add few more items');
                  e.preventDefault();
                }
                }
              });
        })($, $(document));


        Dialog XML

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          jcr:title="Configure Card Component"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
          helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Text">
  <content
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
    <layout
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
      <column
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
          <fieldset
              jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
              jcr:title="Configure Card"
              sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset">
            <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
              <column
                  jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                  sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                  <pages
                      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                      sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
                      class="full-width"
                      eaem-nested=""
                      fieldDescription="Click '+' to add a new page"
                      fieldLabel="Add Card">
                    <field
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                        acs-commons-nested="JSON_STORE"
                        maxMultifieldLimit="4"
                        minMultifieldLimit="2"
                        name="./props">
                      <layout
                          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                          sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                          method="absolute"/>
                      <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <column
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                          <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <headline
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldLabel="Headline"
                                maxlength="50"
                                name="./headline"/>
                            <text
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
                                fieldLabel="Text"
                                name="./byline"
                                required="{Boolean}false"
                                useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true">
                              <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <format
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                                <misctools
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                                <spellcheck
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    features="*"/>
                              </rtePlugins>
                            </text>
                            <textAlignment
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
                                fieldLabel="Content Alignment"
                                name="./alignContent">
                              <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <text
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    text="Center"
                                    value="center"/>
                                <button
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    text="Left"
                                    value="left"/>
                              </items>
                            </textAlignment>
                            <image
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                fieldLabel="Select image"
                                name="./imageUrl"
                                rootPath="/content/dam"/>
                            <linkpath
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                fieldLabel="Link Url"
                                name="./buttonUrl"
                                rootPath="/content/website”/>
                            <linktext
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldLabel="Link Text"
                                maxlength="50"
                                name="./buttonText"/>
                            <openNewTab
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                fieldDescription="Please check the checkbox to open link in a new tab"
                                fieldLabel="Open link in a new tab"
                                name="./newTab"
                                text="Open link in a new tab"
                                title="Open link in a new tab"
                                value="_target"/>
                          </items>
                        </column>
                      </items>
                    </field>
                  </pages>
                </items>
              </column>
            </items>
          </fieldset>
        </items>
      </column>
    </items>
  </content>
</jcr:root>
```